# Is it okay to embed username in BEARER Authorization Header?

Tags: c#, jwt, webapi

I have an API endpoint created using Web API to create a security Token. So the user passes username:password in a Basic Authorization header. The username/password is verified and a Json Web Token is returned.

Now all my other endpoints that do GETs or POSTs I will pass in the JWT in the Authorization header as a BEARER type. I know typically this is BEARER + (jwt) but would it be just as okay to pass
BEARER + username:(jwt)

The reason I want to pass the username:(jwt) is when I verify the jwt I also want to pull out the username from the jwt claim and compare it to the username passed in the auth header as an extra check.

Does this approach sound good or should I forget about doing the username check altogether because it doesn't add any extra security?

Comment: To understand you correctly: You send the basic auth information together with the JWT? Further the predefined claim `sub` Is used to include the username. Edit: See the openid connect claim definition for standardised claims https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims

Comment: I send a Basic Auth when requesting the JWT. Once JWT is received I want to use a Bearer Auth to call the other API endpoints, I was just asking is it okay to use a username+token pair versus just sending the token in that bearer auth.  As far as the claim I use ClaimTypes.Name when defining the claim in the GetToken code.

Comment: Okay but I don’t understand why you want to send username + token because you could / can place it inside the token.

Comment: I was thinking when calling the other endpoints that maybe a bad actor has only one of the two items to call maybe they have the token but an invalid username and they try to pass an invalid username and a correct token, that I can pull the username inside the token and compare it to the username passed in as just another way to verify that they should have possession of the token.  So are you saying I just don't need to do that additional check? Joma is also saying the username can't be verified. My thought was it could be verified against the one inside the token.

Comment: I also wanted to avoid just pulling the username from the token and then doing a database lookup for the username. This is my first time using JWT and I want to make sure just possession of the Token is really good enough after doing a login process. The concept makes me a little nervous. So please forgive my questioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from adding the username outside of the token, however
you can add as many claims to your token as you need and can include the username. These claims can be retrieved from your client application or Web API through the IHttpContextAccessor.

In your client/API you can then do something like this to retrieve the claims:

```
List<Claim> claims = _context.Request.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
```

Where _context is of type IHttpContextAccessor.

This obtains the Subject property of your encoded token, which is a ClaimsIdentity consisting of a list of the Claims that have been added when creating your token.

You can add the username outside of the token, however everything you need can be stored more securely and retrieved from the token itself after the client/API has authenticated the bearer token.

In addition, you can use the claims to add extra authorization when accessing other classes within your client/API.

All the other claims types like sub, iat and so on are properties within the token after it is authenticated on your client/API end. What you need to do during token creation is to use the SecurityTokenDescriptor to create the token descriptor like this (abbreviated):

```
SecurityTokenDescriptor descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username)}),
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiration_in_minutes),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
      SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
```

You will need to ensure the namespaces are in your source:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
```

When I run this to generate the token and then decode the token in https://jwt.io/ in get:

```
{
  "unique_name": "usernam@xxxx.xxx",
  "sub": "usernam@xxxx.xxx",
  "nbf": 1622285741,
  "exp": 1622287503,
  "iat": 1622285741
}
```

Adding the claim using JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub exposes the sub in the token.

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Andrew: I did create my SecurityTokenDescriptor almost verbatim the way you did it. But I was being told that the ClaimTypes.Name is incorrect but I see you have it as Name as well. Also I am having no issue retrieving my username from the claims once the token is sent back to the server from the client.

Comment: I have just experimented with this a bit on my local dev environment and I have managed to get the Sub to appear in the token, I will edit my answer and hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the username/userid in the **[sub](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2)** claim.

The claims inside of the token are signed. The username/userid(sub) is signed, no need to verify if the username/userid is ok/valid.

In your case the **BEARER** **Username**:**Token**

**Username**(No signed, can be changed,  can't be validated):

**Token**(claims/header/signature - all content is signed/validated)>

Username/userid outside token don't add extra security.

**System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub** to avoid write "sub" in the claim name. This namespace is located in **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** nuget package.

Comment: Joma: I was aware that the username was changeable and that is why I would be verifying against a signed username in the token as an additional check that the passer of the token is a good actor. Do you believe the token ALONE with its normal jwt validations is secure enough? In my opinion the jwt validations just ensure the token didnt change from the time of issue until passing it back to the server.

Comment: Another issue is I am using System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes for when I am defining my SecurityTokenDescriptor and SUB isn't one of the available choices. All the examples I have seen people are using the ClaimType.Name in code for the username. Is it possible that ClaimType.Name gets translated or mapped to SUB? Or do I need to hard code "SUB" in the code?

Comment: By the way, the whole idea for checking the passed username against the token embedded username came from this article. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-web-api/ in step 3.

Comment: The attacker send needed username and the token. The token content  can't be changed by signature protection but the username is easily changed.

Comment: To avoid this problem(copy token in another browser/machine), in the token request phase you can send a random_key to server, this key is associated to JwtToken-User and stored in the server DB, this random_key also be stored in your client and encrypted with the client/browser fingerprint(deviceId) to avoid copy in another machine. Every request the server returns the Encrypt(jsonResult, random_key) in the client we need to Decrypt(encryptedResult, random_key).

Comment: This is just an idea, it is not 100% safe but it can make the attackers' work more difficult. There is no 100% secure system. You can do very sophisticated things, but while more sophisticated it can make the software a bit slow for the sake of security.

Comment: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub to avoid write "sub" in the claim name. This namespace is located in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt nuget package.